# My wordpress site is not loading and displays error

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress site is not loading and displays the following error in the console. Can anyone help me out with this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disable owl carousel. It looks like that's what's causing the error. If you can't get to the admin page, rename the plugin folder using ftp.

Comment: there are no carousel plugins

Comment: Whay's your theme-some have owl carousel included, which is why you may not see a separate plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a conflict of plugins' jquery. If you can access the wp-admin dashboard, navigate to the plugins and try to disable **carousel wp plugin** and reload, if that is the error then try to update your plugins.

Comment: there are no carousel wp plugins

Comment: Then try to install carousel plugin, It looks like it once existed in your application. Try to reinstall it and observe the error

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this plugin [jQuery Updater](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-updater/)