# Wordpress site not loading and displays the loading icon

Tags: wordpress

Hi my WordPress site is not loading, I tried installing query monitor plugin which tells the below stats but I am not able to debug this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My wordpress site is not loading and displays error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54064191/my-wordpress-site-is-not-loading-and-displays-error)

Comment: Looks like you are missing JS composer